# Do you have to know method of encryption to Brute Force decrypt It?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Been reading a decent amount about encryption and brute force attacks, but from all that I read on the brute force attacks its simply trying possible key after possible key until you come up with good data.
  My question is, doesn't that require you to know how the data was encrypted in the first place?
   For example, if I were to get a hold of a file that I knew was encrypted, but didn't know if it was encrypted using AES, Serpent, and Twofish (Not to mention of it multiple algorithms in cascade) , would it require to attempt to decrypt it using each method using each possible key for said algorithm?

Comment: Yes, in order to decrypt something you need to know the encryption algorithm - even if you have a key, let alone when you don't.

Comment: Addition: Please don´t start to believe that keeping the algo a secret is more secure. Kerkhoff. (doesn´t matter if you invented a new algo without telling anybody or if you´re just using one without telling which one)

Comment: So why wouldn't it be more secure?  So if I have an encrypted file, that is named "Encrypted using AES with a 256 bit key" it would be the same security as a file that had a different (but for sake of argument precisely the same strength) that was unknown algorithm?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity - If you only get cyphertext, with no access to encrypt/decrypt code, given equal strength of encryption, a secret novel algorithm is more secure; but how often is that the case? You will often need public code (which can then be decompiled),  or it is likely you will have a bug that was not discovered because too few eyes looked at your algorithm/code which would compromise the encryption strength. Also, if your scheme is compromised, (and you should always expect that), a key is easy to replace; the algorithm, not so much.

Comment: So in theory the unknown algorithm would be more secure, however the benefits gained would not be worth the risk in the real world.